# Python - loop time performance reduction

Tags: python, pandas, loops, time, jupyter

I have the following code:

```
#Create an empty data frame to store item affinity scores for items.
itemAffinity= pd.DataFrame(columns=('item1', 'item2', 'score'))
rowCount=0

for ind1 in itemList:
    item1user = itemuser_dict[ind1]
    for ind2 in itemList:
        if ind1 == ind2:
            continue
        item2user = itemuser_dict[ind2]
        commonUsers = len(item1user.intersection(item2user))
        affinity_score =  commonUsers / len(item1user)

        #Add a score for item 1, item 2
        itemAffinity.loc[rowCount] = [ind1,ind2,affinity_score]
        rowCount +=1
```

It took me long time waiting for process (hours) with i7-7700 with only 2000 items in itemList. I would like to ask if there is any way to speed up this code performance because I am having large itemlist with > 50k items ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you want to know how, start by providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Adding rows with `loc` is quite inefficient (every time you add a row the columns' underlying arrays are recreated).

Instead, prepare all the data and create the whole dataframe at once:

```
lines = []
for ind1 in itemList:
    item1user = itemuser_dict[ind1]
    for ind2 in itemList:
        if ind1 == ind2:
            continue
        item2user = itemuser_dict[ind2]
        commonUsers = len(item1user.intersection(item2user))
        affinity_score = commonUsers / len(item1user)
        lines.append({'item1': ind1, 'item2': ind2, 'score': affinity_score})


itemAffinity = pd.DataFrame(data=lines, columns=('item1', 'item2', 'score'))
```

Keep in mind that `columns` is not necessary, but it makes sure the columns will be in the order you expect them.

Also keep in mind that you have an O(n^2) algorithm (nested `for` loops on the same list) and it is not clear if `(item1user, item2user)` is the same as `(item2user, item1user)`. If so, you can greatly decrease the number of iterations by using `itertools.combinations`:

```
import itertools   

combinations = itertools.combinations(itemList, r=2)

lines = []
for ind1, ind2 in combinations:
    item1user = itemuser_dict[ind1]    
    item2user = itemuser_dict[ind2]
    commonUsers = len(item1user.intersection(item2user))
    affinity_score = commonUsers / len(item1user)
    lines.append({'item1': ind1, 'item2': ind2, 'score': affinity_score})

itemAffinity = pd.DataFrame(data=lines, columns=('item1', 'item2', 'score'))
```

Comment: Thank @DeepSpace, I will try your way !